# Como ocultar o hacer url que me oculte el nombre de la carpeta con url personalizado

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hola quisiera saber como hacer este tipo de URL en PHP para una carpeta, dejo ejemplo

https://futbollibre.net/embed/eventos/?r=Ly9lcy1jZG4uY29tL3N0cmVhbS9mci9iZWluNS5odG1s

Como se hace este tipo de URL al final de mi enlace? es para ocultar y no diga por ejemplo https://futbollibre.net/canal.php si no que diga https://futbollibre.net/?r=xxxxxxxxx

> ?r=Ly9lcy1jZG4uY29tL3N0cmVhbS9mci9iZWluNS5odG1s

Gracias, espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Interesante pregunta, muchos miembros de la comunidad diran que no es valida, pero seria bastante util que alguien respondiera a esta pregunta, yo tampoco se darte una respuesta que tenga la suficiente calidad (ya que yo lo haria de otra forma diferente que quizas ya exista), a mi se me ocurre hashear la `URL` , pero quizas no sea lo mas adecuado, pues si el navegador no reconoce luego la ruta de tu carpeta la pagina no podra cargar la informacion asociada, bueno quien sabe, a lo mejor estoy divagando y no es asi.